# References and Books for the basics

Tags: reference-request

I started studying again recently, I forgot plenty of stuff.

But there are 2 areas that I am really struggling.

- The procedures to prove and demonstrate theorems.
- The basic math necessary for cryptography.

Do you guys have any books and references that are easy to learn about those two items?

Thank you!!

Comment: I really like "Introduction to modern cryptography" from Lindell and Katz. It includes everything you need.

Comment: Thank you ! I will go after that book.